# solve y cube equation in runtime

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am doing cropping a object in real time using c++. Here I know 2 coordinates of points A and B. I want to find 3rd point Z which is perpendicular to AB line. Z(x3,y3). It mean ABZ angle is 90. I gained 2 huge equations when I have used BZ slope and BZ distance. I have simplified it and gain following equation.

`y3 ( y3 (k1 + y3) + k) = k ;`

here k1 , k2 , k3 are Constance which has given. But `k1 , k2 , k3` are not equals to each other.
I want to find y3 here. Please help me.

Comment: Simplify your equation in terms of y3 then. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Try posting here instead: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @JonCage: I really don't believe that this qualifies as a _research level math question_.

Comment: @Jon: Better is this: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The cubic equation has [an exact solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots). It's ugly but there you go.

Bear in mind that there will be pathalogical cases where numeric instabilities show up. If accuracy is important you should use more than one method.

[This guy](https://web.archive.org/web/20030114210538/http://www.planet-source-code.com:80/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=627&lngWId=3) has solution code, and [Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20180130091709/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.cubic.equations.html) has some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds overly complicated, at least if I've understood your
problem.  If there are no other constraints on Z (other than it be on a
line perpendicular to AB at B), then:

```
Z.x = B.x - (A.y - B.y);
Z.y = B.y + (A.x - B.x);
```

solves the problem.  If there are additional constraints on Z, the above
expression still gives a point that, with B, defines the line.
Depending on the constraints, calculating the actual Z may be more or
less complicated, but it still shouldn't involve cubic equations.

If you do need to take a cube root, of course, the simplest solution is to use the standard function `cbrt`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want to solve a cubic equation

> x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0

and you already have two solutions x1, x2 and are looking for the third solution x3
then you can do this by observing that

> x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = (x-x1)(x-x2)(x-x3),

and hence that

> -a = x1 + x2 + x3

or

> x3 = -a -x1 -x2

Hence finding the third solution of a cubic given the other two solutions is trivial.